# is it a good idea to create an enum for the key names of session values?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-state, session-variables

instead of doing

```
 session("myvar1") = something
 session("myvar2") = something
 session("myvar3") = something
 session("myvar4") = something
```

is doing

```
enum sessionVar
   myvar1
   myvar2
   myvar3
   myvar4
end enum


 session(sessionVar.myvar1.tostring) = something
 session(sessionVar.myvar2.tostring) = something
 session(sessionVar.myvar3.tostring) = something
 session(sessionVar.myvar4.tostring) = something
```

would be better?

Comment: I recommend re-tagging as session-variables and session-state as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of using constants for the session keys, I'm using my own type-safe session object, which looks like this (sorry this is in C#, see below for a VB version):

```
public class MySession
{
  // Private constructor (use MySession.Current to access the current instance).
  private MySession() {}

  // Gets the current session.
  public static MySession Current
  {
    get
    {
      MySession session = HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] as MySession;
      if (session == null)
      {
        session = new MySession();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
      }
      return session;
    }
  }

  // My session data goes here:
  public string MyString { get; set; };
  public bool MyFlag { get; set; };
  public int MyNumber { get; set; };
}
```

Whenever I need to read/write something to/from the session, I can use my typesafe session object like this:

```
string s = MySession.Current.MyString;
s = "new value";
MySession.Current.MyString = s;
```

This solution results in several advantages:

- I have a typesafe Session (no more type-casts)
- I can document all session based data (by commenting the public properties in MySession)
- When adding a new element to the session, I don't have to search the solution to check if the same session-key was already used somewhere else.

**Update:**
Here's a VB version (automatically converted from the C# version). Sorry, but I don't know VB and so I didn't know how to write the properties in VB:

```
Public Class MySession
    ' Private constructor (use MySession.Current to access the current instance).
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Gets the current session.
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Current() As MySession
        Get
            Dim session As MySession = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("__MySession__"), MySession)
            If session = Nothing Then
                session = New MySession()
                HttpContext.Current.Session("__MySession__") = session
            End If
            Return session
        End Get
    End Property

    ' My session data goes here:
    Public MyString As String
    Public MyFlag As Boolean
    Public MyNumber As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: This is clean and simple.  I like it.

Comment: Perhaps post a VB version for Fredou.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you do not offer an IEnumerable implementation, but one could argue that it should not be needed except for complex types that are stored as lists of some sort.

Comment: interesting one, this would remove a lot of re-casting and make the code a lot cleaner. I'm going to try it and I will probably mark this as the answer. Back in a few minutes.

Answer (score 9):

Only if those values are related. Otherwise use plain old constants.

Comment: I'm hoping for a type-safe Session in the next ASP.Net

Comment: constant would remove the need of .toString, which is very good

Comment: @Joel: look at my answer for my approach

Answer (score 4):

How about:-

```
public static class  SessionVar
{
  public static readonly string myVar1 = "myVar1";
  public static readonly string myVar2 = "myVar2";
  public static readonly string myVar3 = "myVar3";
  public static readonly string myVar4 = "myVar4";
}
```

This allows you to use:-

```
session(SessionVar.myVar1) = something;
```

Comment: Why do you prefer using readonly over const for a session key string?

Answer (score 0):

For the simple thing of removing all of the string key references, I would go with global static/shared constants visible at application scope.

Otherwise, the strongly typed simple wrapper for session variables is a superior alternative, and it's far more OOP-friendly considering that you get intellisense and Object Browser compatibility.

The only way I can see the enum being of much value is to be used to index into an array or a similar list.  But even then you have to cast the enum to an int.

So, you could have an array that you load at application startup with all of your session variable keys and then an enum for the indexes. However, given that the Session object derives from HttpSessionState, which derives from IEnumerable, you should be able to just do a foreach loop over the session variables, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I've used classes like this to make a typed session/cache wrapper.  You may need to add additional code to the get/set, but I'll leave that up to you.

```
internal class SessionHelper
{
    private const string  myVar1Key = "myvar1";

    public static int MyVar1
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[myVar1Key];
        }
        set
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[myVar1Key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about the C#....

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked a while ago and an "answer" has already been picked. But I just came across it. Martin's answer is good. However, to assist anyone who stumbles across this in the future, if you really want a slick way to deal with Session, read this [post](http://blog.theobjectguy.com/2009/12/session-with-style.html). I don't think you'll find anything easier.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that avoids certain disadvantages of the other solutions posted by keeping the structure of the Session variables intact. It is simply a type-safe shortcut to get and set Session variables.

It's C#, but I posted some auto-generated VB.NET at the end.

The best solutions I have seen (the accepted answer and the one by TheObjectGuy) require a custom class that is stored in a Session variable, and then is pulled from the Session to access its properties with something like MySessionClass.Current.MyProperty.

The problem with this is that if you are currently using (or may use in the future) something other than an InProc Session-State mode (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), the whole class would have to go through serialization to access a single property.

Also, that means you lose the IEnumerable and ICollection implementations offered by the actual Session, if you need those. With my solution, you can simply access the actual Session if you need this functionality.

You can easily use these session variables and they are type-safe. It can be used alongside statements like Session["MyProperty"], which will allow for conversion of an existing project one reference at a time. So:

```
int myInt = (int)Session["MyInt"];
Session["MyInt"] = 3;
```

becomes:

```
int myInt = SessionVars.MyInt; 
SessionVars.MyInt = 3;
```

Here is the actual class. The CallerMemberName requires .NET 4.5, but even if you are using an older version you could still manage it by explicitly passing the propertyName. Also, the types of the properties must be nullable to make it act exactly the same as standard Session["MyProp"] calls because a non-set

```
public static class SessionVars
{
    private static T Get2<T>([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[propertyName] == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[propertyName];
    }

    private static void Set2<T>(T value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[propertyName] = value;
    }

    public static int MyInt { get { return Get2<int>(); } set { Set2<int>(value); } }
    public static bool MyBool { get { return Get2<bool>(); } set { Set2<bool>(value); } }
    public static string MyString { get { return Get2<string>(); } set { Set2<string>(value); } }
}
```

I even wrote a code snippet to facilitate adding these properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>SessionVars Property</Title>
    <Author>kevinpo</Author>
    <Shortcut>sv</Shortcut>
    <Description>Adds a property for use in a SessionVars class</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>type</ID>
        <Default>int</Default>
      </Literal>
      <Literal>
        <ID>property</ID>
        <Default>PropertyName</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
      <![CDATA[public static $type$ $property$ { get { return Get2<$type$>(); } set { Set2<$type$>(value); } }]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

I'm a C# guy, so this VB.NET is just auto-converted by http://converter.telerik.com/:

```
Public NotInheritable Class SessionVars
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Private Shared Function Get2(Of T)(<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = "") As T
        If HttpContext.Current.Session(propertyName) Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Return DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session(propertyName), T)
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub Set2(Of T)(value As T, <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = "")
        HttpContext.Current.Session(propertyName) = value
    End Sub

    Public Shared Property MyInt() As Integer
        Get
            Return Get2(Of Integer)()
        End Get
        Set
            Set2(Of Integer)(value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared Property MyBool() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Get2(Of Boolean)()
        End Get
        Set
            Set2(Of Boolean)(value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared Property MyString() As String
        Get
            Return Get2(Of String)()
        End Get
        Set
            Set2(Of String)(value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```