# architectural considerations in strongly typed complex session object with tempdata like behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to architect a strongly typed complex session class with temp data like behavior. I'm a bit confused as to the how to how to set the values to ensure data persistance.

I have a few questions below the code sketch

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{...
  ServiceObject _serviceObject;
  public SomeService(){
    _serviceObject = new ServiceObject();
  }

public SomeMethod(int z){
  if (ServiceObject.A != null){
    _serviceObjct.A = SomeMethodToGenerateA(z);
  }
  return _serviceObjct.A; 
}


[Serializable]
private class ServiceObject{
  public string A {
   get { return GetFromSession().a;}
   set { var sO = GetFromSession();
        sO.a = value;
        StoreInSession(sO);}
 }


 prop B ...
 prop C ...
 prob D ...

 private const string ServiceObjectKey = ServiceObjectKey 
 private void StoreInSession( ServiceObject nO ){
   Session[ServiceObjectKey] = nO;
 }

 private ServiceObject GetFromSession( ){
   return (ServiceObject)Session[ServiceObjectKey]; 
 }

 public void ClearObject(){
   Session[ServiceObjectKey] = new ServiceObject();
 }
```

}
}

q1. Do session variables work by reference?  ie. would

```
public string A {
    get { return GetFromSession().a;}
    set { var sO = GetFromSession();
          sO.a = value;}
 }
```

work instead of

```
public string A {
    get { return GetFromSession().a;}
    set { var sO = GetFromSession();
         sO.a = value;
         StoreInSession(sO)}
}
```

q2. Are there any additional considerations I should be thinking about for this object? At some point it may have to be moved into an out-of-proc storage. It going to access session a bunch (like up to 12 times per request!)

q3. does this design pattern have a name?

if you get 2/3 questions you win!

Also, I intend to use this as a temp data object
.At end of request in the onactionexecuted method, I'm going to clear the object [ if(!actionresult is RedirectResult), then reset the object]

*Meta: (if this question is more appropriate on a forum then on the SO site, please pm me with where I should post it and I'll promptly remove it. I'm kind of aware this q isnt a good s.o. fit.)*

Comment: Check these out it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035136/strongly-typed-sessions-in-asp-net

Comment: Another one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16656/Manage-ASP-NET-Session-Variables-using-the-Facade

Comment: Haha, what a noob, the right answer is to use HttpRequest.Context.Items to store the data. This way it will last one request